# Opening PKCS 7 Certificate files

Tags: pkcs#7

How can I open text files which seem to be PKCS #7 Certificates.  These were archived onto floppy discs in the late 90s and have now been burned onto a CD.  I am using windows 7 on my computer

Comment: What do these text files contain? Perhaps it would be best to post the contents of one of these files.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL and its [pkcs7 command](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs7.html) may help you to decode your documents. Adapt the parameters to your own needs.

```
openssl pkcs7 -in myfile.pem -print_certs -text
```